# How to ensure easy maintainablilty while developing Struts application?

Tags: jsp, web-applications, struts

I've worked on a few projects on Struts 1.3 but sometimes the application just becomes difficult to modify in the future. I follow Dao objects , Business Delegator classes to ensure separation of concern but still i am having problems with them.

Can anybody tell any good practices to follow so that i don't have any problems in the fututre !!

Answer (score 0):

- Use some dependency injection
  framework to decouple classes ([Spring + Struts](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/70-integrating-struts-with-spring-1.html), [Guice + Struts](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Struts2Integration))
- Employ
  behavior driven design for functional
  tests ([jbehave.org](http://jbehave.org/))
- Employ test
  driven design to have your code
  tested ([StrutsTestCase](http://strutstestcase.sourceforge.net/) for [jUnit](http://www.junit.org))

Making the code testable will help having it maintainable. For more resources use Google/Stack Overflow search.

Comment: I am a novice programmer. Can you define these in details ? or point out any resources ?